# Align and resize canvas in CSS

Tags: html, css, canvas, vmware-clarity

I am using `VMware's Clarity` for my UI and came across an issue where I am unable to align or resize my canvas.

```
 <div class="main-container">
    <div class="content-container">
        <div class="content-area">
            <canvas id="canvas1" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid"></canvas>
            <canvas id="canvas2" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid"></canvas>
            <canvas id="canvas3" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid"></canvas>
            <canvas id="canvas4" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

I wish to align all the canvas one after the other, have also explicitly defined the size in `<style>` but no luck it just wont't resize. Also included `width` and `height` parameters inside canvas. 
[image]

I'd like to place the canvas in a way (shown in the picture above) also making sure that they are `responsive` at the same time. Can someone help me with the **positioning** of the canvas?

Comment: The width/height properties don't set it's size in the DOM, they set an available pixel size **inside** the canvas (Not necessarily 1:1 with on screen pixels), you will want to use CSS for layout (Maybe a grid/flexbox layout?)

Comment: `<style>
#canvas2{               
    width:20px;
    height:20px;   
}
</style>` like this?

Comment: Could you pls help me out with the positioning and resizing of the canvas?

Comment: I'm not an expert with the canvas element but I _think_ if it needs to be responsive it also needs a JavaScript solution that can dynamically update the height/width.  Just playing around with css grid I suspect that there are limitations to what can be done wrt width/hight in css. https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-62104718-canvas-exploration